# SSRS: Calculate % from 'counted' calculated fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

Very new to SSRS so unfamiliar with the syntax - Using Report Builder 2.0.

I've built a very simple table in Report Builder to display the total number of appointment slots made available to patients, and the total number of these slots that have been booked.

I'd like to add an additional column to show the % of booked slots (i.e. Available Slots/Booked Slots *100%):

```
| Total Slots | Booked Slots | % Booked |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
|    2000     |     1250     |   62.5%  |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
```

Both the 'Total Slots' and 'Booked Slots' values are based on same field ('Booked_Flag') from the dataset. This field carries a 'Y/N' value.

The 'Total Slots' column has the underlying expression: `=Count(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value)`

The 'Booked Slots' column has the underlying expression: `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value="Y",1,0))`

Please can anyone describe the most appropriate way to calculate the '% Booked' figure?

I've tried this: `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value="Y",1,0)) / SUM(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value)` but it throws the following error - which I'm presuming means I can't perform a calculation on top of another calculation:

```
The expression used for the calculated field '=SUM(IIF(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value="Y",1,0)) / SUM(Fields!Booked_Flag.Value)' includes an aggregate function. Aggregate functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.
```

Greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Instead of using the fields use the actual textbox value. ReportItems!Textbox1.value

Comment: Could you modify the data to return the 0 or 1 value instead of 'Y'/'N'? That way you could just simply sum.

Comment: Thanks @Snowlockk - I've given this a try but it's throwing me a `#Error` in the report - any suggestions why this might be?

Comment: Thanks @RossBush - I guess I could try casting the value in the StoredProcedure, but I was keen to see if it's possible to handle all the calculations in the report layer.

Comment: Might be a divide by zero error. use the following code Public Shared Function SafeDivision(numerator as Decimal, denominator as Decimal) as Decimal

            If denominator = 0.0

                        Return 0.0
            End If
            Return numerator / denominator

End Function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access the content of the report cells and calculate using those. It's simple in your case.
Let's a assume in the report design, the cell that contains '2000' is called TextBox1 (check the properties to get the name) and the cell that contains '1250' is called TextBox2 then your % column expression would be something like

```
=ReportItems!TextBox2.Value / ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
```

The just set the format of the calculated column to `p1` (Percent with 1 decimal place) and your done.

Comment: @Alan_Schofield - many thanks, however, I'm getting a `#Error` showing in the table cell when I run the report

Comment: Have you made sure the textbox names are correct? I've just tested this in case I had done something stupid but it works fine. If you still have issues, post an image of the report design and the exact expression you used.

Comment: @Alan_Schofield cracked it, thank you. I was mistakenly using the names of the column header cells in the expression instead of the names of the cells containing the actual value - changed them out and bingo. Many thanks for your help.